# parse error = Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5.)"

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"3 DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [getMagaListsWebData length]);
    NSString *recievedXML = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:getMagaListsWebData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [recievedXML release];
    //重新加載xmlParser
    if(getMagaListsXmlParser){
        [getMagaListsXmlParser release];
        getMagaListsXmlParser = nil;
    }
    getMagaListsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:getMagaListsWebData];
    [getMagaListsXmlParser setDelegate: self];
    [getMagaListsXmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
    [getMagaListsXmlParser parse];
    if (![getMagaListsXmlParser parse]) {
        NSLog(@"parse error = %@", [getMagaListsXmlParser parserError]);
        //theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:getMagaListsRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    }
}
```

I received  error message:

```
parse error = Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain
  Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5.)"
```

Answer (score 2):

A really useful trick is to Spotlight the offending error/domain

`NSXMLParser.h,  NSXMLParserPrematureDocumentEndError = 5,`

Seems you have a problem with your inbound doc, probably an unbalanced block somewhere.